# Error uploading file using dropbox graham (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I've got a form and when I click submit and It calls the controller but this gives me an error:

- Class 'GrahamCampbell\Dropbox\Facades\Dropbox\WriteMode' not found

Also I tried to create a Folder in my dropbox to check If there are some problem to call the class but It works.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GrahamCampbell\Dropbox\Facades\Dropbox;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Test;


class ArticulosController extends Controller
{

public function store(){

            $file = fopen('path/test.pdf', 'rb');
            $size = filesize('path/test.pdf');

            Dropbox::uploadFile('test.pdf', Dropbox\WriteMode::add(), $file, $size);
            Dropbox::createFolder('/example');  //This function works

        return redirect ('/home');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spite of I tried to call WriteMode class, for some reason the function doesn't call WriteMode correctly. So I finally use [Dropbox Adapter](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/adapter/dropbox/) and know it works.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with laravel dropbox.
But the package that you are using doesn't contain the WriteMode class.
The package does require the dropbox/dropbox-sdk package, and this does contain the WriteMode class (https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/Dropbox/WriteMode.php).

So if you `use Dropbox\WriteMode` I think it will work.

Comment: How I should call this class? I tried but I can't. I had this file in project\vendor\dropbox\dropboxs-dk\lib\Dropbox. 
In addition, If I call this function from resources/layouts works well.